# .Htaccess and Html 2 Questions

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, header, webserver

So lately while hosting my website I notice my website spits out on its headers that it is hosted on php 5.6.6 e.t.c is there any way I could stop this on .htaccess I know its possible on html but I think in .htaccess it would be much cleaner.

Second Question and more importantly is how can I filter if there is an ~ on the search "*example.com/~test*" I want it to be able to redirect this to an 404 or just the main page. So basically if there is an ~ on the request then it should redirect it to an 404 Page.

Any help is appreciated just put it down below.

Comment: Please limited yourself to a single question (or at least some *very* closely related ones) to a stackoverflow question. This is likely to be closed as too broad.

Comment: "I know its possible on html" — No, it isn't. There is no way to control what response headers a webserver will output from inside an HTML document.

Comment: Well I found an answer to my first question, Do you guys know an answer to my second question?

Comment: Also header_remove('x-powered-by'); on html/php does remove it.

Comment: `header_remove` is a PHP function. It is not HTML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found answer for my first question, But no luck with the second question, please leave some help.

 The Answer I found to work is going into your php.ini and change 
expose_php = on
 to 
expose_php = off